# Convert *.ico to svg path based

Tags: svg, ico

I have some ico files (24x24) with monochrome colors (white background, black the icon content itseft). I want those icons to be converted into svg path based. So similar to that:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
   <path d="M20 19V3H4V19H2V21H22V19H20M16 9H18V11H16V9M14 11H6V9H14V11M18 7H16V5H18V7M14 5V7H6V5H14M6 19V13H14V14.82C13.55 15.14 13.25 15.66 13.25 16.25C13.25 17.22 14.03 18 15 18S16.75 17.22 16.75 16.25C16.75 15.66 16.45 15.13 16 14.82V13H18V19H6Z" />
</svg>
```

I do not find any online converter or offline tool to simply transfer the pixels into such a path format. I want the converter to to that **without changing any of the quality of the icon**.
Does anybody know a tool which I can use for that?

Comment: You can auto trace/vectorize raster images to svg (e.g. using potrace). But the results will never be on par with a handcrafted vector graphic. So there's no chance especially using tiny images as 24 x 24px as an input. So it's more reasonable to replace the icon's manually by searching for native vector graphics (or commisioning a graphic designer) than relying on tracing algorithms. Besides the .ico format can contain multiple sizes/versions – I doubt any converter will bother about it.